# Is my string of inequalities correct?

Tags: complex-numbers, real-numbers

s and a are complex numbers.  Then

$$|s| - |a| \le |s-a| \le |s+a| \le |s| + |a|$$

1st and 3rd inequalities I am confident about, but I am not sure about the middle inequality.

Thanks,

Comment: The middle inequality is not right. However, it is certainly true that $|s-a|\le |s|+|a|$.

Comment: Let $a = -s$ to see why

Comment: you don't need the middle one any way. it is true that $||s|-|a|| \le |s\pm a| \le |s| + |a|$

Comment: Ok, got it.  Thanks so much, everyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not true:

$$|1-(-2)|>|1+(-2)|$$

$|s-a|$ is the distance from $s$ to $a$ and $|s+a|$ is the distance from $s$ to $-a$. So if you consider the segment $\gamma$ that joins $a$ and $-a$ and the perpendicular bisector $r$ of $\gamma$, your inequality is true only if $s$ is at $r$ or in the same half-plane as $a$ respect to $r$.